# Flutter Android Studio (the doctor check crashed)

Tags: flutter

Anyone can helps ?

I am installing flutter ,but when I run flutter doctor ,I got this issue:

```
E:\flutter_project\first_app>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale zh-CN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at D:\flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (7 days ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android
    • Java binary at: D:\Java\jdk\bin\java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[☠] Android Studio (the doctor check crashed)
    X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know
      about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    X FileSystemException: Exists failed, path = ''D:\AS'.plugins' (OS Error: 文件名、目录名或卷标语法不正确。
      , errno = 123)
    • #0      _Directory.existsSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:94:7)
      #1      ForwardingFileSystemEntity.existsSync
      (package:file/src/forwarding/forwarding_file_system_entity.dart:43:33)
      #2      ErrorHandlingDirectory.existsSync.<anonymous closure>
      (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:479:22)
      #3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:573:14)
      #4      ErrorHandlingDirectory.existsSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:478:12)
      #5      AndroidStudio.pluginsPath (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio.dart:186:52)
      #6      AndroidStudioValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_studio_validator.dart:46:17)
      #7      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:32)
      #8      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:109:18)
      #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
      #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
      #11     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1789:10)
      #12     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1777:12)
      #13     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1708:12)
      #14     asyncGuard (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:109:3)
      #15     Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:199:9)
      #16     Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:303:47)
      #17     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:50:47)
      #18     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1192:12)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #19     FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #20     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #21     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #22     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
      (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #23     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #24     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #25     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #26     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #27     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
      <asynchronous suspension>


[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.1)
    • IntelliJ at D:\Intelij\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.2
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\zhongdongjing\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.124
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.64

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

My computer information :
windows 10,
Android Studio : 4.2
flutter : 2.4.0

I had seach in many webs ,but still not have a solution .I am crashing ..
If I need to change the path ,how and where am I able to change ?

Thank you so much ！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"` this problem happens whan the path to AndroidStudio is not found. Make sure you use the correct path to AndroidStudio.

You may need to restart the computer for this to take effect.

Run `flutter doctor` again

Comment: Hi Jaime !!!!You 've saved me !! It works ,thanks so much my friend !!!!

Answer (score 1):

I Already tried but after that rise same error -[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it putting this C:\Windows\System32 in the Path environment variables, hope this works for somebody.